# Error "All columns of a table must have the same length" occurs when group by is used in SQL

Tags: group-by, dolphindb

I have a table as shown in the following figure:

[image]

I want to group the data in the “value” column by the “name” column, and select the row with the maximum value for each group. I tried a statement: `select max(value) as max_value,other from t group by name`, but an error was reported: `All columns of a table must have the same length`. Does anyone know where the problem is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you like to aggregate `other` column in this group by? You must specific one if you want to return it in group by result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group by` clause requires all selected columns to be used with an aggregate function, such as `max`, `min`, `avg`, etc. However, the “other” column in your statement is not being aggregated, which will result in columns of different lengths. That’s why the error occurs.

You can use `context by` clause with the following script:

```
select * from t context by name csort value desc limit 1
```